# SQL Query taking too long to execute and getting duplicates in columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to get Quantity of a product based on the Customer account. and each product have an account linked with it. one account to one product. and also getting duplicate of data in this. because of multiple products and accounts.

Screen Shot of result while query execution stopped in the middle

[image].

```
select vAcc.sName
    ,vProd.sName 'Product Name'
    ,CASE WHEN vGRN.Status='GRN' THEN vGRN.Qty  ELSE 0 END 'GRN'
    ,CASE WHEN vGRN.Status='OTH' THEN vGRN.Qty ELSE 0 END 'OTH'
    ,CASE WHEN  vGRN.Status='CNV' THEN vGRN.Qty ELSE 0 END  'CNV'
    ,vPack1.Qty 'Raw Material'
    ,vPack2.PQty 'Package Item'
    ,vPack3.FGQty 'Finished Goods'
    ,CASE WHEN vDel.Status='DN' THEN vGRN.Qty  ELSE 0 END 'DN'
    ,CASE WHEN vDel.Status='CNV' THEN vGRN.Qty ELSE 0 END 'CNV'
    ,CASE WHEN  vDel.Status='OTH' THEN vGRN.Qty ELSE 0 END  'OTH'
from vCore_Account vAcc
left join (select a.iMasterId,a.Customer,b.Qty,a.Status,b.Item,b.BatchNo from vCore_GRN a inner join  vuCore_GRN_Product_Details_Details b on b.iMasterId=a.iMasterId) vGRN on vGRN.Customer=vAcc.iMasterId
left join (select a.iMasterId,a.CustomerName,b.Qty,b.Items,a.BatchNo from vCore_Packaging a inner join vuCore_Packaging_Packaging_Details_Details b on a.iMasterId=b.iMasterId where a.iMasterId>0) vPack1 on vPack1.CustomerName=vAcc.iMasterId
left join (select a.iMasterId,a.CustomerName,b.PQty,b.Product from vCore_Packaging a inner join vuCore_Packaging_Packing_Items_Details b on a.iMasterId=b.iMasterId where a.iMasterId>0) vPack2 on vPack1.CustomerName=vAcc.iMasterId
left join (select a.iMasterId,a.CustomerName,b.FGQty,b.Product from vCore_Packaging a inner join vuCore_Packaging_Finished_Godds_Details b on a.iMasterId=b.iMasterId where a.iMasterId>0) vPack3 on vPack1.CustomerName=vAcc.iMasterId
left join (select a.Status,a.CustomerName,b.Qty,b.Item from  vCore_DeliveryNotes a inner join vuCore_DeliveryNotes_Product_Details_Details b on b.iMasterId=a.iMasterId) vDel on vDel.CustomerName=vAcc.iMasterId
left Join vCore_Product vProd on vProd.iMasterId=vGRN.Item OR vProd.iMasterId=vDel.Item OR vProd.iMasterId=vPack1.Items OR vProd.iMasterId=vPack2.Product OR vProd.iMasterId=vPack3.Product 
where vAcc.iMasterId>0
```

Comment: Are you aware you can sum(field) and group by (field)

Comment: Yes am aware of that aggregate function SUM and GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Tried, Adding SUM on Respective Quantity Column. And grouping another columns. It is also taking too long.

Comment: I recommend you start by filtering one category / customer to ensure you are getting the correct output. Optimising it is a bit hard on mobile phone

Comment: Ya sure ill do and update you

Comment: even filtering isn't working its taking too much time.

Comment: Since everything starts with "v".. are these tables or views?

Comment: what database is this?

Comment: Perhaps try a select * from each tablebto see what is making it slow - it will require more detail about what element of the query is running slow before it's optimised